# Hold Terminal open

Tags: macos, terminal

Sometimes I'm working on something in the terminal, and then go away. When I come back, I want to resume what I was working on, but sometimes I forget, and hit <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>, which closes all the terminal windows automatically, no questions asked.

Is there a command that can "hold" a Terminal tab so that I don't accidentally close what I was doing?

As an example, what I want can be hackishly accomplished by running `sleep LARGE_NUMBER` in the tab I want to keep open.

Then if I accidentally hit <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>, it won't close directly, and rather present me with the following, which gives me an opportunity to cancel and resume what I was doing:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by running `cat`, which will make it wait for input forever.

For faster usage, an alias can be defined in `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias h="cat"
```

Comment: Runnin `top` should also work.

Answer (score 4):

There's an option to show a dialog before closing any tab in the preferences:

[image]

Translating the screenshot to english is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Right, but most of the time I don't want it to ask... Although I guess this could work for some.

Comment: @patrix , you are my hero :)  Not all answers have to be so serious.

Comment: @houbysoft, this is probably your best approach. A gentle confirmation dialog isn't that bad given your propensity toward command-q.

Comment: @houbysoft you can't have it both ways, either you get asked every time or not at all. Remembering to run `cat` in another tab in cases you don't to accidentally close is even more cumbersome.

Comment: @patrix I'm tempted to revert the answer so the website isn't quite so monoglot and humourless.

Comment: @patrix: not in my case. It's basically just so I can mark a tab as non-closable when I put the computer to sleep and expect to resume work in an hour or more (so I'd have to do it like once per day max).

Comment: You can have more than one settings profile ("Basic" is a settings profile), and you can change the profile of an existing terminal. So, make a copy of your default profile, change this setting to “Always”, and whenever you want to “mark” a terminal to prompt you, open the Inspector and change to the “always prompt” profile. (Shell > Show Inspector)

Comment: :-) I changed it back due to popular demand...